# Java SOAP proxy initialization exception

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, jax-ws

I am deploying a set of Java-based AMF web services to GlassFish v3. This all works fine in the development environment, but fails in the staging environment where it is currently being setup:

Dev: GlassFish 3.0.1 Web Profile, Java JDK 1.6.0u22.
Staging: GlassFish 3.0, Java JDK 1.6.0u22.

I realize the GlassFish version and edition is different, and I have requested it to be updated to match the development environment. Because I have a hard time imagining this to be the cause of the problem though, I thought I'd ask here if anyone had any ideas.

The Java-based AMF service interacts with a .NET-based SOAP service. The Java-service has proxies generated off the SOAP service using `wsimport`. The error occurs when trying to initialize the SOAP proxy as far as I can tell.

The stack trace is as follows:

```
org.granite.messaging.service.ServiceException: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
at org.granite.messaging.service.AbstractServiceExceptionHandler.getServiceException(AbstractServiceExceptionHandler.java:42)
at org.granite.messaging.service.DefaultServiceExceptionHandler.handle(DefaultServiceExceptionHandler.java:33)
at org.granite.messaging.service.ServiceInvoker.invoke(ServiceInvoker.java:121)
at org.granite.messaging.amf.process.AMF3RemotingMessageProcessor.process(AMF3RemotingMessageProcessor.java:56)
at org.granite.messaging.amf.process.AMF0MessageProcessor.process(AMF0MessageProcessor.java:79)
at org.granite.messaging.webapp.AMFMessageServlet.doPost(AMFMessageServlet.java:62)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
[..cut..]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:31)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:128)
at javax.xml.ws.spi.Provider.provider(Provider.java:83)
at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
[..cut..]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to install the full GlassFish Server instead of GlassFish Server Web Profile. Despite the development environment being setup with Web Profile it had remnants of the full GlassFish (specifically the JAXB and JAXWS jar files) that were being picked up there.

The staging environment was clean and only ever had Web Profile installed and thus failed because of the missing dependencies.